# tinyMCE 4.1.9 and Small Window Size Freezes

Tags: javascript, php, tinymce

tinyMCE on the smaller screen sizes seem to just completely freeze. This happens on iPads and on a full-desktop using Chrome but with the window resized. I'm not doing anything fancy:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        tinymce.init({
            selector: "textarea#tinyMCE",
            height: 350,
            toolbar: [
            "undo redo | fontselect | fontsizeselect | bullist numlist | outdent indent | bold italic",
            ],
            plugins: [
            "lists link save paste"
            ]
        });
</script>
```

Any advice? I am using version 4.1.9 (2015-03-10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the error was caused by being wrapped around a couple of Bootstrap divs ("row" and "col-lg-12"). If anyone else runs into this problem, try taking it out of those divs.